# Unexpected path to libprotocd.lib after add gRPC::grpc++ library dependence in CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, grpc, conan

I have a gRPC 1.23.0 compiled by conan(and all dependencies also resolved by conan).
And I have a CMake project, that use grpc library:

```
set (LIB_DEPS
  protobuf::libprotobuf
  gRPC::grpc++
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB_DEPS})
```

When I generate a VS project from this `CMakeLists.txt` in `Linker - Input - Addition Dependencies` property, I have there next value:

```
C:\.conan\data\protobuf\3.9.1\kpa_conan\stable\package\b786e9ece960c3a76378ca4d5b0d0e922f4cedc1\lib\libprotobufd.lib <-- (1)
C:\.conan\data\grpc\1.23.0\kpa_conan\stable\package\d85cccdf40588ac852bd1445d45838487543194f\lib\grpc++.lib
libprotocd.lib   <-- (2)
libprotobufd.lib  <-- (3)
C:\.conan\data\grpc\1.23.0\kpa_conan\stable\package\d85cccdf40588ac852bd1445d45838487543194f\lib\grpc.lib
C:\.conan\data\grpc\1.23.0\kpa_conan\stable\package\d85cccdf40588ac852bd1445d45838487543194f\lib\gpr.lib
C:\.conan\data\c-ares\1.15.0\kpa_conan\stable\package\b786e9ece960c3a76378ca4d5b0d0e922f4cedc1\lib\cares.lib
C:\.conan\data\grpc\1.23.0\kpa_conan\stable\package\d85cccdf40588ac852bd1445d45838487543194f\lib\address_sorting.lib
wsock32.lib
kernel32.lib
```

(1) - expected valid path, that I add in `CMakeLists.txt`

(2),(3) - unexpected and invalid path, that added by `gRPC::grpc++` in `CMakeLists.txt`.
If I change `gRPC::grpc++` to `gRPC::grpc`, lines (2) and (3) will disappear, but path to `grpc++.lib` will disappear too, but I need it.

How to avoid this strange invalid path to `libprotocd.lib` and `libprotobufd.lib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly link against grpc targets you can use:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC CONAN_PKG::grpc)
```

This should contain everything required. 
More details on this approach here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html#targets-approach

Answer (score 0):

I have found workaround solution:

```
find_library(GRPC_GRPC++_LIBRARY NAMES grpc++)
set (LIB_DEPS
  protobuf::libprotobuf
  gRPC::grpc
  ${GRPC_GRPC++_LIBRARY NAMES}
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${LIB_DEPS})
```

And opened the issue about it in gRPC repository: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20578

Comment: Did you try to just do `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CONAN_PKG::grpc})`?

Comment: ```Syntax error in cmake code at
    CMakeLists.txt:66
  when parsing string
    ${CONAN_PKG::grpc}
  Invalid character (':') in a variable name: 'CONAN_PKG'```

Comment: Sorry I made a typo there. The command should be like: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC CONAN_PKG::grpc)`. Without the curly braces. More details on this approach here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html#targets-approach