# Can't build project with gRPC on Linux x64 Release configuration

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, c-ares

I have a project that use gRPC. It successful build on any configuration on Windows(Debug\Release) and on Debug configuration on Linux.
But in Release mode I have next error:

```
ld: cannot find -lnsl
```

In CMake output(link.txt):

```
#debug build
...
 /home/user/data/c-ares/1.15.0/debug/lib/libcares.a /home/user/data/grpc/1.23.0/debug/lib/libaddress_sorting.a
...
```

```
#release build
...
 /home/user/data/c-ares/1.15.0/release/lib/libcares.a -lnsl /home/user/data/grpc/1.23.0/release/lib/libaddress_sorting.a
...
```

What is that strange additional dependence `-lnsl`? And how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve it, `CONAN_PKG::grpc` should be used. From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58589246/4481855